# ACF and Vimeo Upload

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vimeo, vimeo-api, acfpro

I used plugin for https://bitbucket.org/jupitercow/acf-vimeo-uploader-field/src/master/ and unfortunelly it stopped working. Now "Select file" button doesn't make any action. API looks good. Console doesn't display any errors. Variables from JS return correct results. Do you have any ideas?
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Looks like there is already an open issue in the repo. https://bitbucket.org/jupitercow/acf-vimeo-uploader-field/issues/8/upload-button-doesnt-work. I'd recommend to follow up there

Answer (score 0):

See the last two issues:

[image]

It's a plugin bug, so you won't do much about it, unless you're programmer yourself. I'd suggest waiting for the author to fix it, or find a way to reach your goal without the need of having Vimeo upload field.